# How to set up CSS/JS cache busting using PHP and Git on high traffic site?

Tags: php, git, caching, browser-cache

I need to set up cache busting for CSS/JS on a high traffic site that uses PHP and Git.

I know how to get the current Git version using "`git describe --tags --always`". I need to do this so PHP will cache this value and only run every 5 minutes or so. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad.  So you currently have a caching system implemented...does it have a method of clearing?  I assume it would and I assume you should piggy back on top of that.  This is something we can't help with unless we know more on what you are doing.

Secondly, you are interested in having a commit trigger your publishing.  This doesn't seem like a good idea to me.  I have no idea your publishing setup but there must be times when you want to commit changes and you don't wnat them to go live yet.  Thus it would make more sense to me to invalidate your cache when you pubish.

Regardless, if you parse the output of your git command

```
$version = exec("git describe --tags --always");
```

and compare this with your current version (stored in db or a simple txt file) and execute any commands it should work.

Comment: I don't have a cache system set up at the moment. I would like to set it up so the URLs to the CSS/JS have "?version=XXXXXX" appended at the end. So whenever a new build is pushed to the production server, PHP would get the Git tag and inserted it in place of XXXXXX. My question is, how to make the PHP cache this variable so PHP only runs the git describe command once every five minutes, instead of each time a user loads the page.